# How to use builtin functionality of webjob sdk to send service bus message

Tags: servicebus, azure-webjobssdk, webjob

I want to push service bus message using inbuilt functionality provided by the azure web job sdk. https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Service-Bus  this link is mentioned how to do but not clear yet

Answer (score 0):

[Service Bus](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Service-Bus) has provided all prerequisites and code snippets for you to receive / create Service Bus messages.

> To write a function that creates a new queue message use the **ServiceBus** attribute and pass in the queue name to the attribute constructor.

**Create a single queue message:**

```
public static void CreateServiceBusQueueMessage(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("inputqueue")] string queueMessage,
    [ServiceBus("<your-queue-name>")] out string outputMessage)
{
    outputMessage = queueMessage;
}
```

> The output parameter for creating a single queue message can be any of the following types:
>
> - string
> - byte[]
> - BrokeredMessage
> - A serializable POCO type that you define. Automatically serialized as JSON.

**For creating a Service Bus topics message:**

```
public static void CreateServiceBusTopicMessage(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("inputqueue")] string queueMessage,
    [ServiceBus("<your-topic-name>")] out string outputMessage)
{
    outputMessage = queueMessage;
}
```

Moreover, you could also use `TimerTrigger`, `FileTrigger`, `QueueTrigger`, `BlobTrigger`, `EventHubTrigger` to trigger the execution of your function to create service bus queue/topic messages. Details you could follow [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions) and [Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus Sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/ServiceBus).

Comment: thanks for the answer, actually those information i could see from the sdk. but could not come up with correct code example.  is CreateServiceBusTopicMessage  inbuilt function?

Comment: In general, `CreateServiceBusTopicMessage` is just a custom method defined under `Functions.cs` which would be picked up by WebJobs SDK, you could rename it as you expected and add multiple methods under `Functions.cs`.  AFAIK, Azure WebJobs SDK would pick up the proper public methods under public classes. Moreover, you could download the sample https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/ServiceBus to run it locally, and modify it to have a better understanding of WebJobs.